# Angular JS accessing controller data from a filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have data in a JSON format, which I then display using `ng-repeat`. I've written a filter that finds the position of the `%` simbol and then slices the string. Now I want to concatenate another string at the end of it (`field.FIELD6`) from the ng-repeat of my view. I've added the JSON data from my controller onto `$rootScope`, but don't know how to proceed from here.

Is there a way to do that? Are filters the wrong approach and how would you do this?

Thanks for the help.

app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('peroApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .filter('klicaj', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var n = input.indexOf("%"); 
      var out = "";
      //if string doesn't contain %
      if(n === -1) {
        out = input;
      } 
      //if string contains %
      else {      
        out = input.slice(0, n);
        //CONCATENATE STRING HERE
      }
      return out;
    };
  });
```

main.html:

```
<ul ng-repeat="field in live">
  <li> {{ field.FIELD1 }}</li>
  <li> {{ field.FIELD2 }}</li>
  <li class="url">{{ field.FIELD3 }}/{{field.FIELD4 | klicaj }}/{{ field.FIELD5 | klicaj }}</li>
</ul>
```

main.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('peroApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($rootScope) {   
    $rootScope.live = [
  {
    "FIELD1":2,
    "FIELD2":0,
    "FIELD3":"SCR",
    "FIELD4":"FT",
    "FIELD5":"1X2",
    "FIELD6":"",
    "FIELD7":"3way"
  },
  {
    "FIELD1":8,
    "FIELD2":1274,
    "FIELD3":"SCR",
    "FIELD4":"FTaI!5",
    "FIELD5":"ATTTL!2!%1$s",
    "FIELD6":"(\\d+.\\d+)",
    "FIELD7":"Asian total awayteam after 5 innings"
  }
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass argument to filter by augmenting the filter with object you want to pass separated by `:`

Example: if you want to pass controller reference to filter `klicaj`

```
{{field.FIELD4 | klicaj:controllerRef }}
```

Now second argument in the filter function will be controllerRef.

You can also pass more than one reference to the filter.

Comment: so if I understand this correctly, I need to pass my controller as an argument to the filter, and then I can reference the $scope.live from it?

Comment: got it, the final solution looks like this: `{{field.FIELD4 | klicaj:field.FIELD6 }}`. Now I can access it in the filter. Thanks